# How can I make the App Routing work in this case?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created an Angular App and in one of my services, after I call the http.post method and subscribe to it I want to redirect to the same page I was before, but that page has a parameter eg. "http://localhost:3000/profile/aRandomName "

I tried to call the router method but it's not working.

This is a part of my service

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router){}

updatePositiveRanked(thisUserUsername:string, rateValue:string) {
       const updatePositiveData = {
           thisUserUsername: thisUserUsername, 
           rateValue:rateValue
       }



       this.http.post<{message:string}>("http://localhost:3000/api/profile/positiveRank", updatePositiveData)
       .subscribe(response => {
           console.log(response.message);
           this.router.navigate(['profile/'+thisUserUsername]);
       })
    }
```

And here is my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PostListComponent } from './posts/posts-list/posts-list.component';
import { PostCreateComponent } from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';
import {AuthGuard} from './auth/auth.guard';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/getProfile/profile.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',component:PostListComponent},
  {path:'createPost', component:PostCreateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: "auth", loadChildren: "./auth/auth.module#AuthModule"},
  {path:'profile/:username',component:ProfileComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I expected to be redirected, can you help me out, please with this, I'm new to Angular. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass route parameters like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['profile/', thisUserUsername]);
```

This should fix the navigation error.